# es6 how to add a property when it was true

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
let b = 'es6'

let obj1 = {
  [b]: 'asdasda',
}

console.log(obj1)

// [object Object] {
//   es6: "asdasda"
// }

let a = undefined

let obj2 = {
  [a] : 'asd',
}

console.log(obj2)

// [object Object] {
//  undefined: "asd"
// }
```

i want add the property when is was exist.

when i send a ajax i need to judge the params

before this, i judge everyone and get exist together and send it

but i think it will have some cool way to resolve it

can everyone help me ？

Answer (score 0):

A conditionally added property will have to be run in code, rather than in a static object declaration.

```
let a = undefined;
let obj2 = {};

if (a !== undefined) {
    obj2[a] = 'asd';
}
```

If this is not what you were looking for, then please clarify your question as it is not entirely obvious what question you are asking.

A property name itself cannot be `undefined`.  Property names are strings so something like you show in your comments `{undefined: "asd"}` where the property is actually the value `undefined` is not something Javascript can do.  A property name could be the string `"undefined"`, but not the actual value `undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

```
let a = undefined;

let obj2 = {};

if(obj2.a != undefined){
 obj2.a = "Test";
}

console.log(obj2);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.